# Set Layout Manger formula for recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a simple question please help. I use recyclerview with a custom `SpannedGridLayoutManager` and it work fine. But, I need to change the formula for the item design. Here I provide the image link:

[Link for current output plus what I want in addition](http://saadusman.androidstudent.net/CronaProject/20200727_153413.jpg)

I only want one thing, please open pic i also set text on picture. I want 6 item in 2 rows , currently there is one row with 3 items. Below code has the formule that I use:

```
 SpannedGridLayoutManager manager = new SpannedGridLayoutManager(
            new SpannedGridLayoutManager.GridSpanLookup() {
                @Override
                public SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position) {
                    // Conditions for 2x2 items
                    if (position % 12 == 0 || position % 12 == 7) {
                        return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);
                    } else {
                        return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            3, // number of columns
            1f // how big is default item
    );
```

Here `position % 12 == 0 || position % 12 == 7` I think need to be changed. Please Help me!

Comment: Try `position % 18 == 0 || position % 18 == 10`.

Comment: @Pawel Thank you soo much! I works. Pawel can you do me one more favor. If i want 3 rows of 3 item then now what is formula?

Comment: For each extra row add column count x 2 to the number you're calculating modulo of.

Comment: Can you send me one example please